# Form validations not working properly in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Form validations are not working properly in codeigniter. I have wrote the below given code. When I click on submit button, form gets submitted automatically without any values. (ie, no validation is performed)

**Code of View**

```
     <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    echo form_open_multipart("form_validate/validate");
        echo form_fieldset("Registration Form");
        echo "Name :".nbs(5).form_input('name','').form_error("name","<span style='color:red;'>","</span>").br(1);
        echo "Username :".nbs(5).form_input('username','').form_error("username","<span style='color:red;'>","</span>").br(1);
        echo "Email :".nbs(5).form_input('email','').form_error("email","<span style='color:red;'>","</span>").br(1);
        echo "password :".nbs(5).form_input('password','').form_error("password","<span style='color:red;'>","</span>").br(1);
        echo "Confirm-Password :".nbs(5).form_input('cpassword','').form_error("cpassword","<span style='color:red;'>","</span>").br(1);
        echo "Mobile :".nbs(5).form_input('mobile','').form_error("mobile","<span style='color:red;'>","</span>").br(1);    
        echo form_submit('submit','Register').nbs(5).form_reset('reset','Cancel').br(1);    
        echo form_fieldset_close();
        echo form_close();
    ?>
    </body>
 </html>
```

**Code of controller**

```
<?php

class User extends CI_Controller
{
    public function main()
    {   
        $this -> load -> helper('html');
        $this -> load -> helper('form');
        $this -> load -> view('form');      
    }

    public function validate(){
            $this   ->  load    ->  library("form_validation");
            $this   ->  load    ->  helper("html");
            $this   ->  load    ->  helper("form");
            $this   ->  form_validation ->  set_rules('name','NAME','required');
            $this   ->  form_validation ->  set_rules('username','USERNAME','required|min_length[3]|max_length[10]|alpha');
            $this   ->  form_validation ->  set_rules('email','Email','required|valid_emails');         
            $this   ->  form_validation ->  set_rules('password','Password','required|matches[cpassword]'); 
            $this   ->  form_validation ->  set_rules('cpassword','Confirm-Password','required');
            $this   ->  form_validation ->  set_rules('mobile','Mobile','required|exact_length[10]|integer');;

        if($this -> form_validation ->run()==false)
                {
                $this -> load -> view('form');
                }
                else
                {
                echo "form has been Submitted";
                }
    }
}

?>
```

What can be wrong with my code?

Comment: you have load helper `form` and `html` twice, make it once

Answer (score 0):

In controller try this

```
class User extends CI_Controller
{
 public function __construct(){
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library("form_validation");
 }
 public function main()
 {          
    $this -> load -> view('form');      
 }
 public function save(){       
        $this   ->  form_validation ->  set_rules('name','NAME','required');
        $this   ->  form_validation ->  set_rules('username','USERNAME','required|min_length[3]|max_length[10]|alpha');
        $this   ->  form_validation ->  set_rules('email','Email','required|valid_emails');         
        $this   ->  form_validation ->  set_rules('password','Password','required|matches[cpassword]'); 
        $this   ->  form_validation ->  set_rules('cpassword','Confirm-Password','required');
        $this   ->  form_validation ->  set_rules('mobile','Mobile','required|exact_length[10]|integer');;

    if($this -> form_validation ->run()==false)
    {
       $this -> load -> view('form');
    }
    else
    {
       echo "form has been Submitted";
    }
  }
}
```

And in view change this

```
echo form_open_multipart("form_validate/validate");
```

to

```
echo form_open_multipart("form_validate/save");
```

Comment: Form_validation is a default library in codigniter.so we did't change method name.  please  send me another solution